# Mongodb distinct query returns error for .distinct("state",{$where:"this.state.length>2"}) for null values

Tags: mongodb

I want distinct states having state's string value greater than 2 characters.

My query is,

```
db.company.distinct("state",{$where:"this.state.length>2"})
```

it shows me following error,

> "errmsg" : "exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   null\n    at _funcs1 (_funcs1:1:40)",

Please help

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer,
db.companies.find({"state":{$ne:null},$where:"this.state.length>2"})

Answer (score 1):

The error basically means the property is not defined,and referencing it at such under JavaScript code when it does not exist raises the error.

Instead use [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/):

```js
db.company.distinct("state", { "state.2": { "$exists": true } });
```

In that way it's a simple test that can actually even use an "index" to speed up results. And basically put, if there is an element present in the array with an index of 2 ( n-1 ) then there are more than 2 elements in the array.

You should never revert to JavaScript evaluation unless you really have to, since the whole invocation and interpretation is going to be a lot slower that native coded operators.